# What options are there for GLSL shader development on OS X?

Tags: macos, opengl, glsl, shader

Apple's Shader Builder is not terribly advanced. I was wondering if there are any better choices for OS X other than running something under bootcamp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a tool called [Shader Maker](http://cg.in.tu-clausthal.de/publications.shtml#shader_maker) which is based on Qt. [Lumina](http://lumina.sourceforge.net/) is also open source.

One of the best GLSL editors I've encountered is ATI's RenderMonkey, but there is sadly no Mac OS X version.

Quartz Composer (included with the OS X development tools) has some GLSL editing functionality but it's probably not what you want. [This](http://www.memo.tv/amoeba_dance_caliper_remote) is an example of something developed using the tool.

Answer (score 0):

### Quartz Composer

While it might seem more appropriate to use Apple's OpenGL Shader Builder you should be using Quartz Composer. You can create a shader and see the changes you make in real-time, it highlights errors and allows a wide range on inputs including a Teapot. There are numerous predefined shaders to check out.

Like the Shader Builder, Quartz Composer is contained in the Xcode Graphics Tools download on [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/).

Comment: Where can you edit the shader? I understood your answer as if it is possible to only use the GLSL editing part in quartz composer.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, RenderMonkey is the best out there IMO. I would run it off bootcamp or virtualize it since it isn't mega heavy on the hardware.

Answer (score -1):

OpenGL Shader Builder, I think it's part of Xcode, as I don't recall ever installing it and I have it.

Comment: The original question is asking for alternatives to OpenGL Shader Builder.